# Stormpath Express Passport save customData or even the default data

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, stormpath

I'm running this sample application of Stormpath Express Passport
`https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-passport-express-sample`

I can't wrap my head around how can you post a form and save customData or even the default data like the given name and surname. Overall I would appeciate if I could get a HTML(Jade or EJS) example with lines I need to write in `app.js` or `index.js`. I've been struggling with this for 4 evenings.

I've tried multiple tutorials for Express, Stormpath, but none of them are meant to work with this sample application. I always had to install multiple new modules, but even that didn't get anything to work.

I've would highly appreciate if someone from Stormpath or really anyone who has experience with it, would help me with my problem and perhaps update their tutorials on the website as well, because some seem to be outdated.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote that article and project, and I'm also the author of [express-stormpath](https://docs.stormpath.com/nodejs/express/) (*our new library which makes this stuff much easier*).

The simplest way to do this is in a route (using our passport library) is like so (**note, you might need to upgrade to the latest version of our Node library to make this work**):

```
req.user.getCustomData(function(err, data) {
  data.someValue = 'blah';
  data.someOtherValue = {
    woot: 'hi',
    nope: 'there',
  };
  data.save(); // persist this data to Stormpath
  res.send('done!');
});
```

If you're using our Express library, you can do this a bit easier, here's an example:

```
var express = require('express');
var stormpath = require('express-stormpath');

var app = express();
app.use(stormpath.init(app, {
  expandCustomData: true,
}));

app.get('/data', stormpath.loginRequired, function(req, res) {
  req.user.customData.color = 'black';
  req.user.save();
  res.send('stored data!');
});

app.listen(3000);
```